# Python Zip Files Read

Tags: python, zip

I am new to python, I have a .zip file which has multiple sub-folders and each sub-folders has multiple .txt files. I am trying to read all .txt files But I want to store files folder specific into a variable But I am not able to do so.

For eg:
"test.zip" which has three folders "a","b","c", each has multiple(>10,000) .txt files
I want to read all files inside folder "a"  and store it into a variable a_file and same with folder "b" and "c"
I tried the following code:

```
for file in os.listdir():
if file.endswith('test.zip'):
    zfile=zipfile.ZipFile(file)
    fnames= [f.filename for f in zfile.infolist()]
    for subfile in fnames:
        if fnames == "a" . #name of a folder 
          if subfile.endswith('.txt'):
              lines=zfile.open(subfile).read()
              print(lines)
```

But the code is extracting all files from multiple folders and not displaying any output ***maybe because of if condition***
 it. Instead of a reading folder specific and storing it
 Thank You in Advance for helping

Comment: can you share an entire file path of a single file?

Comment: There is at leas one issue with your code - `fnames` is a list, so how can you compare it with a string: `if fname == "a"`?
Maybe you meant something like
`if subfile == "a": lines = zfile.open(subfile).read() ...`?

Comment: @Jeril /Users/akshitshah/Downloads/FolderName/test.zip/a

Comment: @amitr i tried that way also `subfile=="a"`  but still not working,

Comment: is there no text file? or can you share the entire file path including the text file , for  a single one

Comment: @Jeril ` /Users/akshitshah/Downloads/FolderName/test.zip/a/.txt`

Comment: why is there no filename? its only `.txt`

Answer (score 0):

That happened because zip file lists the files as follows:
a/a1.txt a/a2.txt b/b1.txt b/b2.txt
So you need to separate files from directory using split('/')
 
You could try this:

```
import os
from zipfile import ZipFile
for file in os.listdir():
    if file.endswith('test.zip'):
        zfile = ZipFile(file);
        fnames = [f.filename for f in zfile.filelist];
        for subfile in fnames:
            dir_name = subfile.split('/')[0];
            if(dir_name == 'a'):
                if(subfile.endswith('.txt')):
                    lines = zfile.open(subfile).read();
                    print(lines);
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much but apparently, this is not displaying any output

Comment: @GuruReddy there is a blank output, It runs without producing any output

Comment: @AkshitShah just put print(fnames) statement below fnames and paste the output here